# Display the error messge

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

I am doing server side vaildation. I want to display the error message in toster. Now am able to display the status code. But I have to display the error message also,

```
 return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "please enter the name");
```

My **ajax** is like below

```
 statusCode: {
            201 
                toastr.success('Added Successfully');
            }
        }
    }).fail(
             function (xhr, textStatus, err) {                    
                 toastr.error(err);                    

             });
```

In toaster it is showing bad request but i want to dispaly the message ("please enter the name") also. i tried the following link.bt nt worked for me.
    http://forums.asp.net/t/1781489.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the 
    ReasonPhrase:

```
var error = "please enter the name";
var response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error);
response.ReasonPhrase = error;
return response;
```